# java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level:..)

Tags: sql-server, java-8, kerberos, windows-authentication, jtds

I am getting following exception while trying to make KERBEROS connection using JTDS

```
Debug is  true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true KeyTab is C:/Users/../KerberosConfDir/app1.keytab refreshKrb5Config
is false principal is http/domainusername.foo.com tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
                [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed
Pre-authentication information was invalid (24)
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: GSS Failed: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:654)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:371)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:184)
        at JDBCKerberosTest.main(JDBCKerberosTest.java:85)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: GSS Failed: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.sendMSLoginPkt(TdsCore.java:1976)
        at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.login(TdsCore.java:617)
        ... 3 more
```

This is the code I have written,

```
try {
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "KerberosConfDir";
   Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
   System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug", "true");
   System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", filePath+File.separator+"login.conf");
   System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", filePath+File.separator+"krb5.ini");
   System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
   Properties dbConProp = new Properties();
   dbConProp.setProperty("user",user);
   dbConProp.setProperty("password",pwd);
   String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+hostName+":"+port+"/master;instance="+instanceName+";domain="+mydomain+";useNTLMv2=true;useKerberos=true;";
   con = d.connect(connectionUrl, dbConProp);
   rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid");
   if(rs.next()) {
       System.out.println("auth_scheme : "+rs.getString("auth_scheme"));
       if(rs.getString("auth_scheme").equalsIgnoreCase("KERBEROS")) {
           System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  JTDS : KERBEROS Connection successful %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
       } else {
           System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  JTDS : KERBEROS Connection failed %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%");
       }
   }
} catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if(rs != null) {
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if(con != null) {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

my login.conf configuration as below

> com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate {
>   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
>   useTicketCache=false
>     doNotPrompt=true 
>   useKeyTab=true
>     keyTab="../KerberosConfDir/app1.keyTab"
>   principal="domainusername@FOO.COM"
>      storeKey=true
>   debug=true };

my krb5.ini as below

> ```
>      [libdefaults]
>          default_realm = FOO.COM
>          dns_lookup_realm = false
>          dns_lookup_kdc = true
>          ticket_lifetime = 1s
>          forwardable = yes
>          #udp_preference_limit = 1
>
>      [realms]
>          FOO.COM = {
>            kdc = KDC_HOST.FOO.COM
>            default_domain = FOO.COM
>          }
>
>      [domain_realm]
>          .FOO.COM = FOO.COM
>
>      [login]
>          krb4_convert = true
>          krb4_get_tickets = false
> ```

my SQLJDBCDriver.conf as below

> ```
>  SQLJDBCDriver {
>     com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useTicketCache=true >doNotPrompt=true;
>  };
> ```

Have created keyTab file as below

> ktpass /out app1.keytab /princ http/domainusername.foo.com@foo.com /mapuser domainusername /crypto AES256-SHA1 /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /pass domainuserpassword

Can someone help me on this issue ?

Comment: Hi, any update on my above thread ?